# Select name and surname as Customer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have combined name and surname on my select statement as customer but now I am trying separate the name and surname by a comma using the code below but getting an error.

This is my code

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.FirstName,',', c.surname) AS CUSTOMER, e.EmployeeID, d.Description, p.Product, b.BillDate
FROM CUSTOMER c, EMPLOYEE e, DELIVERY d, PRODUCT p, BILLING b
WHERE c.customerid = b.customerid and b.billdate = '15 May 2017'
ORDER BY FirstName ASC;
```

This is my error

```
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 173 Column: 8
```

Comment: Why are you choosing NOT to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?  Your query looks totally broken, quite independent of your attempts to use `CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's `CONCAT` function only takes *two* parameters.  So, you may either nest two calls to `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.FirstName, CONCAT(',', c.surname)) AS CUSTOMER,
       e.EmployeeID, d.Description, p.Product, b.BillDate
FROM CUSTOMER c, EMPLOYEE e, DELIVERY d, PRODUCT p, BILLING b
WHERE c.customerid = b.customerid and b.billdate = '15 May 2017'
ORDER BY FirstName;
```

Or, you may use the ANSI concatenation operator `||`:

```
SELECT c.FirstName || ',' || c.surname AS CUSTOMER,
       e.EmployeeID, d.Description, p.Product, b.BillDate
FROM CUSTOMER c, EMPLOYEE e, DELIVERY d, PRODUCT p, BILLING b
WHERE c.customerid = b.customerid and b.billdate = '15 May 2017'
ORDER BY FirstName;
```